# Does anyone have any tips on figuring out why a Vector Layer didn't load in Pyqgis?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

This is a general question.  I'm stepping through the pyqgis code and the layer isValid() is always False.  I don't see any error messages showing any reason why it wouldn't load.  Other similars have loaded without problems.

Just trying to see if I need to actually download the QGIS source and start stepping through that as well...?  (i hope not)

the first layer loads without problems.  it's referencing a postgis table.  the second doesn't but the another_table is a view. perhaps that makes a difference but there are no error messages or exceptions letting me know what's wrong...

Nothing fancy:

```
    #first vLayer
    self.uri.setDataSource('public','some_table','location','')
    self.first_layer = QgsVectorLayer(self.uri.uri(), 'Some Locations', "postgres")

    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(
        self.first_layer)


    #second Layer
    self.uri.setDataSource('public', 'another_table', 'location','')
    self.second_layer = QgsVectorLayer(self.uri.uri(), 'Another set of Locations', "postgres")

    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(
        self.second_layer)
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: looks like when i changed the postgis view to a table it worked, i.e., the layer.isValid() was fine.  So i guess QGIS 2.4 doesn't support postgres views?

Comment: to create the table i did this:  
create table some_table as select * from some_view;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to provide a field name to be used as primary key by QGIS:

```
self.uri.setDataSource('public', 'another_table', 'location','', 'key_field')
```

Of course, make sure `'key_field'` exists in your view and is a unique field, or else, create a field with such characteristics in your view.

If that doesn't work, see [How to debug 'Layer is not valid error' from Python plugin?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41957/how-to-debug-layer-is-not-valid-error-from-python-plugin/127278#127278), and try passing the SQL that defines your view directly to `setDataSource`, like this:

```
query = 'SELECT key_field, location, ... FROM ... WHERE ...'
self.uri.setDataSource('', '(' + query + ')', 'location', '', 'key_field')
```